# Use of plugins in gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I have a question on the usage of plugins in gradle in general. What features do they provide?

For example, why should I use an Idea plugin if my IDE is intelliJ. What if I don't use that will there be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about Gradle plugins in general, you should read the relevant part of the [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html). It does a good job of explaining the concept.

As for the IntelliJ plugin in particular: no you should generally not add it. IntelliJ can import Gradle projects just fine without it. The only time it makes sense to add it is if you need to customize the import process in a way that differs from the default. But even that is often better done through adding the specific IntelliJ configuration files to your VCS repository. If you like to know more about best practices for this, the [Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/c/help-discuss) are a better match for discussing the different approaches.